# Get count of items based on certain dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to solve this query:

- Column `A` contains an array of dates
- Column `B` contains daily entry of `no` / `yes`

This formula returns the number of occurrences for `no`:

```
=(COUNTIF(b1:b365,"no"))
```

I need to find the occurrences of `no` in the current month only. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

If you have Excel 2007 or later version try COUNTIFS, e.g.

`=COUNTIFS(B1:B365,"no",A1:A365,">="&EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1,A1:A365,"<"&EOMONTH(TODAY(),0)+1)`

or you can use SUMPRODUCT in any version

`=SUMPRODUCT((B1:B365="no")*(TEXT(A1:A365,"mmm-yy")=TEXT(TODAY(),"mmm-yy")))`

Comment: by using this i made a formula to calculate monthly bill of milkman 

=CONCATENATE("Rs. ",(((TODAY())-(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),1)))-COUNTIFS(J6:J381,"a",I6:I381,">="&EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1,I6:I381,"<"&EOMONTH(TODAY(),0)+1))*16)

can you make it short again ?

Comment: +1 for using the `TEXT()` function to simplify the month comparison.  –1 for using `yy` instead of `yyyy`.

Comment: @mahendra Jadhav, try this to shorten a little `="Rs. "&(DAY(TODAY())-1-COUNTIFS(J6:J381,"a",I6:I381,">="&EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1,I6:I381,"<"&EOMONTH(TODAY(),0)+1))*16`

Comment: @Scott - Thanks! I figured it was unlikely that there would be data from Jan 1913 (or even Jan 2113)!

Answer (score 0):

Barry Houdini has given you some great formulas to use. (I really like the SUMPRODUCT one.)

If you are open to another approach you can use a pivot table.

Set up your table like this:

[image]

Then choose "Options" and "Group Selection" like this:

[image]

You'll end up with this:

[image]